# trying to update after Installing docker on parrot os

Tags: docker, updates, parrot-os

I am now on my parrot machine and I tried to install docker on it after that I tried to update my machine but I am still having that issue after I run this `sudo apt update`
and that is the result :

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ara InRelease
Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ara Release
404  Not Found [IP: 13.224.189.54 443]
Hit:4 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lts InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot InRelease
Hit:6 https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ara Release' does not 
have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled 
bydefault.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I'm new to Linux so I'm not entirely sure this is correct, but it worked for me.

Someone in another thread mentioned that his ubuntu mint documentation/version(?) didn't assign the right files by default and he had to change it. Then it dawned on me that Parrot OS isn't ubuntu at all. It's debian bullseye.

So it's probably the same mistake only for Parrot.

Then I changed the URL inside of

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

to

```
https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
```

and it worked!

```
sudo apt update
```

stopped throwing errors and the installation finished as expected.